# Проблемы при создании нового пользователя бд Oracle 18

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Установил Oracle 18. При создание пользователя возникли проблемы. Как создать нового  пользователя, а затем таблицу? Делал через sqlplus, ничего не вышло.

Comment: какие ошибки были?

Comment: Что именно делали? Опишите подробнее ваши действия и какие ошибки появились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для начала

Вариант 1: через sqlplus

```
cmd>set oracle_sid='instance_name'
cmd>sqlplus user/pass@remote_SID@hostname.network
```

или

```
cmd>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Вариант 2: dbForge Studio for Oracle, SQL Navigator

создать пользователя можно так, подробней можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C)

```
CREATE USER sidney 
IDENTIFIED BY out_standing1 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE example 
QUOTA 10M ON example 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
QUOTA 5M ON system 
PROFILE app_user 
PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

создать таблицу можно так, подробней можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)

```
CREATE TABLE EMP 
(
   EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER, 
   LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
   DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER
);
```

Comment: Сначало нужно зайти под пользователем SYS? `SQLPLUS / AS sysdba`

Comment: да, конечно))))